# EZGmail not able to locate credentials.json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, gmail-api

I'm following along with Automate the Boring Stuff's "Sending and Receiving Email with the Gmail API" section, but I'm unable to get the ezgmail API set up. I'm using Jupyter Notebook if that makes any difference.
I've downloaded the gmail API, and run their Quickstart with no issues, but when I try to run the code from the book, I get an error that the system can't find the .json file. Here's my code, which is exactly as is it in the book (with the exception of the file path, which I've changed to 'C:\path\to' just for this):

```
import ezgmail, os
os.chdir(r'C:\path\to\PythonScripts\credentials_json_file') #I have correct file path in my code
ezgmail.init()
```

And I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-ed031accfb24> in <module>
      1 import ezgmail, os
----> 2 os.chdir(r'C:\path\to\PythonScripts\credentials_json_file')
      3 ezgmail.init()

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\path\to\\PythonScripts\\credentials_json_file'
```

I've double checked that the credentials file is in my current working directory with os.listdir, and the file shows up in the output. I've also tried to change the "credentials_json_file" part of the code to "credentials.json_file", remove the word file, json, etc., along with renaming the json file to credentials-gmail.json (as some related posts here suggest), but nothing works.

I've also tried running the code without the os.chdir line, but that just results in the following exception:

```
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [--auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME] [--noauth_local_webserver]
                             [--auth_host_port [AUTH_HOST_PORT [AUTH_HOST_PORT ...]]]
                             [--logging_level {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f C:\path\to\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-5b1dd877-fb2d-4b67-8b7e-88a3d365dc4a.json
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

any help would be GREAT. I've been messing with this for way too long for such a simple introductory piece of code....

Comment: Where is the json file located in relation to the python script?

Comment: Try using forward slashes instead of backward slashes in your absolute file path: `os.chdir(r'C:/path/to/PythonScripts/credentials_json_file')`

Comment: @gmdev the json file and the python script are in the same folder

Comment: @RafaGuillermo just tried it, I get the same message

Comment: If they're in the same folder why do you have to use `os.chdir` at all?